# Dropbox sync api write string in JSON file

Tags: android, json, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to write a JSON string in txt file that contains other JSON objects. The structure of the txt file is:

```
{
"array": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "owner": "email_string",
        "title": "title_string",
        "content": "content_string"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "owner": "email_string",
        "title": "title_string",
        "content": "content_string"
    }
]
}
```

Now in my code, I have built the new String JSON formatted to append after the last object but I don't know how to write the new JSON string after the last JSON object and before the ']' character.
The DropboxFile object has method as getInputStream(), getWriteStream(), getAppendStream(). I suppose i should use one of them but I don't know how. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code where i need to put the writing:

```
DbxFileSystem dbxFs;

dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

DbxPath path = new DbxPath(NOTE_DB_PATH);
dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();
DbxFile file = dbxFs.open(path);

String JSONNote = JSONParser.buildJSONNoteString(title, content, currentUserEmail, id)+"\n";

// TODO Here I have to find the place to write my JSONNote string

dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();

file.close();
dbxFs.shutDown();
} catch (DbxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

}

**SOLUTION:**

```
DbxFileSystem dbxFs;

dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

DbxPath path = new DbxPath(NOTE_DB_PATH);
dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();
DbxFile file = dbxFs.open(path);

String JSONNote = JSONParser.buildJSONNoteString(title, content, currentUserEmail, id)+"\n";
JSONObject newJsonObj = new JSONObject(JSONNote);

String dataString = readFile(file);
JSONObject dataJSON = new JSONObject(dataString);

dataJSON.accumulate("array", newJsonObj);

file.writeString(dataJSON.toString());

dbxFs.syncNowAndWait();
file.close();
dbxFs.shutDown();
```

readfile() method:

```
    protected String readFile(DbxFile file) throws DbxException, IOException{
    FileInputStream in = file.getReadStream();
    int size = in.available();
    byte c[] = new byte[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        c[i] = (byte) in.read();
    }
    String filedata = new String(c, "utf-8");

    in.close();
    return filedata;
}
```

Comment: you want to write JSONNote to file is it correct

Comment: Yes! but not at the end of the file, just after the last JSON object

Comment: you want to add data in json array that you have

Comment: i am not getting what you are doing in your code but i have a code which  will help you in appending data in json array

Comment: Post your code, maybe it is helpful. I think i could have found a solution: I read all the file txt building a String. Then i modify the String obtained using the String method and adding my new JSON string. In the end I reWrite the complete file using Dropbox method. This should work

Comment: and if it help u then please don't forgot to accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read your file using following code

```
public String readFile(String filepath) throws IOException {
File f = new File(filepath);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
int size = in.available();
byte c[] = new byte[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    c[i] = (byte) in.read();
}
String filedata = new String(c, "utf-8");
return filedata;}
```

Then form JSONArray as i have looked at u r JSON structure you can do it in following way

```
String data = readFile("your filepath");

JSONObject data = new JSONObject(data);

JSONArray newarray = (JSONArray)data.get("array");
```

Then you can use "put" method of JSONArray and append data in existing jsonarray . so it will be like

```
newarray.put(index,your_data);
```

then use following code to write the same data to file

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your file name", false);
                    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
                    ps.append(data.toString());
```

and hopefully you are done

Comment: I modified a bit the code, but your solution was great! thank you for the help!